# What does the -tulpn option mean for netstat?

Tags: netstat

For finding out which ports of the machine are being opening by which services, I used:

```
netstat -tulpn
```

I checked the `man` page for `netstat` command, but I found nothing about this option. What's the meaning of the `-tulpn` option?

Comment: Did you read [`man netstat`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/netstat.8.html)?

Comment: Read the man page http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/netstat.8.html , one option at a time (-t, -u, -l, -p, -n)

Comment: You can also visit [Netstat command in Linux](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/netstat-command-linux/), which has snaps showing what you'll get as output for different param.

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Thank you. I thought that it's an individual option, not mixed. Please add an answer then I accept and upvote.

Comment: @M.Rostami Not all Linux / UNIX utilities follow this pattern, but a general rule of thumb is that the long form of an option starts with a double dash (e.g., `--tcp` or `--udp`), and the short form starts with a single dash (e.g, `-t` or `-u`.) And as you have just discovered, some commands allow the short form options to be combined. There are plenty of exceptions, though! Off the top of my head I can think of `tar` which accepts options with or without the dash (e.g., `tar xvzf foo.tgz` is the same as `tar -xvzf foo.tgz`), so always check `info` or `man` pages if in doubt.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As answered in https://serverfault.com/questions/387935/whats-the-difference-betwen-the-single-dash-and-double-dash-flags-on-shell-comm, in a Linux command line;

> A single hyphen can be followed by ***multiple*** *single-character* flags.
>
> A double hyphen prefixes a ***single*** *multi-character* option.

If you look at [netstat man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/netstat.8.html), you will see that (Note that, `netstat -tulpn` is equivalent to `netstat -t -u -l -p -n`):

```
--tcp|-t

--udp|-u

-l, --listening
   Show only listening sockets.  (These are omitted by default.)

-p, --program
   Show the PID and name of the program to which each socket belongs.

--numeric, -n
   Show numerical addresses instead of trying to determine symbolic host, port or user names.
```

So, your command is equivalent to the following long form also:

```
netstat --tcp --udp --listening --program --numeric
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to `man netstat` you can type `info netstat` to get a shorter summary and longer explanation:

```
NETSTAT(8)                      Linux Programmer's Manual                      NETSTAT(8)

NAME
       netstat  -  Print  network connections, routing tables, interface statistics, mas‐
       querade connections, and multicast memberships

SYNOPSIS
       netstat [address_family_options] [--tcp|-t] [--udp|-u] [--raw|-w] [--listening|-l]
       [--all|-a]  [--numeric|-n]  [--numeric-hosts]  [--numeric-ports] [--numeric-users]
       [--symbolic|-N] [--extend|-e[--extend|-e]]  [--timers|-o]  [--program|-p]  [--ver‐
       bose|-v] [--continuous|-c]
```

For `-t -u -l -p -n` above you see `--tcp`, `--udp`, `--listen`, `--program` and `--numeric` without having to scroll.

Scrolling down you can see verbose explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were looking for the man page for netstat(8).

Linux.die.net has man pages for seemingly all Linux tools. See below the man page for netstat(8) which should answer your question.

https://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat

Comment: It is better to point to ***Ubuntu*** man pages: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/netstat.8.html

Comment: Indeed it probably is, but I still answered the question.

Comment: It is not about who wins the right answer tag, it is about helping community by doing so.

Comment: As I mentioned, *I checked the `man` page for `netstat` command*. However, thank you for your response.